# Passing a Variable from one JS function to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ajax to fetch my data based on some select tags. When I select body part it send a request to sub_parts_ajax() function and does it work perfect and when I select disease type from another select tag which links to disease_name_ajax() where I want the id of last selected in the sub_parts_ajax() 
[image]
Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">



 function sub_parts_ajax(id){

    var VAR = {
        myvalue: id
     };

        $.ajax({

            url: 'fetching_parts',
            data: 'id='+id,
            success:function(res){
                //alert(res);
                $("#sub_part").empty();
                $.each(res,function(key,value){
                    $("#sub_part").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Second Function

```
  function disease_name_ajax(typeid){
```

here I want to alert the value named: myvalue

```
alert(VAR.myvalue);

        $.ajax({

            url: 'fetching_names',
            data: 'typeid='+typeid,
            success:function(res){
                //alert(res);
                $("#disease_name").empty();
                $.each(res,function(key,value){
                    $("#disease_name").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    }


</script>
```

Comment: How is `VAR.myvalue` set? If that ID is just the value of the current selection of a select element then you can simply get the value directly from the select element again.

Comment: You can push the `id` inside an `array` and can reuse whenever required.

Comment: Have added a picture check it.. What Im doing is when i select body part it changes the subpart after that I select disease type where i wan to get both ids one from the select body part and one from the select disease type

Comment: how and where are you binding those functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you store the object as a global variable which can be accessed and modified from any function (Not recommended)

Or

You save the value in this case as JSON to a custom hidden input in the DOM which also can accessed from any function.

```
<input type="hidden" id="argVal"/>
 var VAR = { myvalue : id };
 var argJSON = JSON.stringify(VAR);
 $("#argVal").val(argJSON);
```

To retrieve the value from any function

```
 var val = JSON.parse($("#argVal").val());
```

Comment: Why u are using <input type="hidden" id="argVal"/> ?

Comment: It puts lesser load on the browser than using global variables.

Comment: Awww Great, Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Using a Global Variable

```
var Myvalue = {};
```

Then Updating it in the function

```
function function1(id){
Myvalue.value= id;
}
```

Then you can call it at any function

```
function function2(){
alert(Myvalue.value);
}
```